# Matrix function and its argument

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

Suppose that $f$ is a function from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^n$ given by $$f(x) = \left(\begin{array}{c} f_1(x) \\ f_2(x) \\ \vdots \\ f_n(x) \end{array}\right).$$
If the $i$th component of $x$ is changed, I am interested in the change in $f_i(x)$. This is straight forward. I now want to transfer the framework to functions $F$ from $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ to $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$. For simplicity, assume that $X$ and $Y= F(X)$ can be decomposed into $X = P^{-1}\Lambda P$ and $Y = Q^{-1}\Psi Q$ with $\Lambda$, $\Psi$ diagonal. Now I want to identify a change in the $i$th component of $\Lambda$ with one of the elements in $\Psi$. Is this possible at all? If yes, how?

Comment: Look up the Matrix cookbook for dozens of formulas like this

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "a change in the $i$th component of $\Lambda$ with one of the elements in $\Psi$". Could you clarify?

Comment: $\Lambda = \left(\begin{array}{cccc} \lambda_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2 & 0 \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & \lambda_n\end{array}\right)$ and $\Psi$ has a similar structure. Now let's say I increase $\lambda_1$ by a marginal amount $\Delta\lambda_1$. How does $\Psi$ change then? Since $Q^{-1}\Psi Q = F(X) = F(P^{-1}\Lambda P)$, $\Psi$ must somehow depend on $\Lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

Since you find the vector case "straight forward", why not transform the matrix problem into a vector problem, i.e. 
$$\eqalign{
x &= {\rm vec}(X) \\
y &= {\rm vec}(Y) &= f(x) \\
J &= \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \quad&\big({\rm via\,\,straighforward\,\,technique}\big) \\
}$$
Given the decompositions of $(X,Y)$ in terms of $(\Lambda,\Psi)$,
you can use the Khatri-Rao product $(\boxtimes)$ to expand 
$(x,y)$ as matrix-vector products.
$$\eqalign{
x={\rm vec}(P^{-1}\Lambda P) &= (P^T\boxtimes P^{-1})\,{\rm diag}(\Lambda)\;\doteq A\,\lambda \\
y={\rm vec}(Q^{-1}\Psi Q) &= (Q^T\boxtimes Q^{-1})\,{\rm diag}(\Psi) \;\doteq B\,\psi\\
}$$
Then use $J$ to calculate the desired gradient.
$$\eqalign{
dy &= J\,dx \\
B\,d\psi &= J\big(A\,d\lambda\big) \\
\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial\lambda} &= B^{-1}JA
\qquad= \left(Q^{-T}\boxtimes Q\right)JA \\
\frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial\psi} &= A^{-1}J^{-1}B 
\qquad\big({\rm assuming\,}J^{-1}{\,\rm exists}\big) \\
}$$

Comment: One question: We have $Y = F(X)$ so $Y$ is a function of $X$. How can you ensure that $Q$ does not depend on $\lambda$?